# How to collect data of users and create table of online users?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, database, chatroom

I am trying to find a way to collect the details about the users logged in the website right now.
Explain: user enter my website, choose a nickname (input box) and then there are more 5 buttons like yes no questions that he choose to help identify his profile. I want to collect all this data (nick name+what we chose for each button) and then even create a table of those users logged in. Do I must use a DB for that or cookies will do the work? The hard part i'm having right now is how I save the data on each user and how to show the online users in the current session for each of those users.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. To keep the sample simple I have create a 1. A Table in SQL Server, B. Web API in ASP.net, EF Core 3.1, 3. SPA application in Angular 9. I keep everything minimal **without** following best practices. The goal is to show end to end. Instead of taking multiple screen inputs, I have taken inputs inside the first screen. I think this should get you started. Many thanks.

[Source Code URL] https://github.com/vishipayyallore/simple-angular-demo

```
git clone https://github.com/vishipayyallore/simple-angular-demo.git
```

[image: git clone command]

You can create a small component to show the details of the logged in users.

[Currently Logged in Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQoKR.png)

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3IrM.png)

[Web API in ASP.Net Core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr8t4.png)

```
    USE [webapidemodb]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserPreferences]    Script Date: 23-02-2020 22:37:15 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPreferences](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserNickName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsGraduated] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsProgrammer] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPreferences] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
    [DF_UserPreferences_Id_1]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPreferences] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
    [DF_UserPreferences_CreatedAt]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreatedAt]
    GO
```

Comment: i don't see sample

Comment: let me re-phrase. Do you need a code sample? if Yes I will create one and publish to my GitHub by tomorrow. Will that work?

Comment: oh i'll be glad if you could help me with that! i will explain again so you won't need to work hard. user enter his nickname press on "next" button and then there are more 5 questions with yes/no button for each one (can be also radio button) once he finished with all the questions he press "finish" button and then he can see the table with all the users that logged in right now.

Comment: Got it. I will work on this weekend and publish the url.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I guess best I can do right now is to watch some tutorials to understand better this programming world.

Comment: Did you maybe finish with the sample?

Comment: I am working on it today India time. You will get it by Sunday EOD India time.

Comment: Links and images added. Please review the edited answer

Comment: Hi there, why can't i download\clone the files from the git?

Comment: @HelpMePlease, I have updated the Repository to the new location and updated the solution. [Source Code URL] https://github.com/vishipayyallore/simple-angular-demo

git clone https://github.com/vishipayyallore/simple-angular-demo.git

Comment: How do I run the whole project? I tried opened it with Visual Studio Code and then npm install -> ng build -> ng serve but that doesn't work. could give me further help on how to run this?

Comment: Sure. Do you have SQL server installed on your local laptop? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you testing ["Firebase Realtime Database"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). but finally it depends on your current development stack and project budget you provide to choose what database which suits your need.

Comment: need something free and easy :)   i know how to create DB in SQL but don't know how to connect between the two. i need it to be in real time, that once user finished to choose nickname and choose the 5 buttons to identify him , he will see table with all the other users in the current session (with their data = nick name+5 buttons)

Comment: take a look at firebase pricing. it also has free plan and lots of capabilities. and its really easy to use.[https://firebase.google.com/pricing] [https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules] [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database] [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth]

Comment: ok will do, can you help me to understand how to save each pressed button to create the data?  each button has his own value to a specific question and all those pressed buttons help me to create the user identification

Comment: as first steps choose one front-end framework and take some courses/tuts to getting started, then when you get familiar, learn about how you can handle form data, so you will be able to create your own forms and manage its data, finally you have to learn firebase and http basics to create some requests to firebase to save/restore data. for a complete guide on angular please visit https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/